# Mismatch between some CoreBluetooth naming and Documentation, like didConnectPeripheral and didDiscoverPerpherial in CBCentralManagerDelegate

Tags: ios, delegates, swift3, core-bluetooth, xcode8

I am new to iOS and Swift.  I had some code from previous XCode which I updated to what I thought was the new cool way to do things, according to the new naming conventions.

For example I had a function in a CBDelegateManager class:

```
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
...
}
```

But then I changed it to

```
        func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
...
}
```

The 2nd matches the online help for the API.  Both compile fine, but the 2nd does not get called.
Am I missing something?

Comment: It should be `func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) ` ie. an _ before `central`

Comment: To add more info to @Paulw11's comment, Swift 3 changed the method signatures. Just be careful with the online doc, on this page https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518937-centralmanager it's the "real" doc/signature for the method, note that one (https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate)

Comment: @Paulw11 -- thank you, but I'm still confused. I inserted "_ " and now get warning "Extraneous _ in parameter: 'central' has no keyword argument name".  And, I still see you have didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral, but (thank you to @Larme), the doc page indicates just didDiscover.   Is this about "objC" compatibility?

Comment: IMPORTANT UPDATE:  I had forgotten that I had the "Legacy Swift" Build setting on.  This is (most of) what was so confusing to me.  I didn't mention it, but I was trying to compare results I was getting from the Playground (Mac, Swift 3 only) to my iOS code (Legacy on).   I have updated my code now to have Legacy off, and converted to Swift 3 API.  And, it works.